# Lenovo charging led blinking

Tags: lenovo-laptop

The red charging led of my Lenovo B50-30 is blinking while charging. Is this normal behavior or is something defect? I never really looked at this led, so I don't know how it was in prior days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On page 12 of the [user manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/b40_b50_ug_en.pdf) it states

> **Power and battery status indicator**
>   **Blinking amber:**
>    The battery has a charge of 20% or less and the AC power 
>   adapter is connected to the computer.

I guess what you call red is what they call amber.

Comment: I believe Andrew is correct.  Most leds to indicate there is a problem by being either yellow or amber.

Comment: So there is no 'real' problem?

Comment: @Motte001 It should change to blinking green once the charge is above about 20%. Would you say it is *definitely* red, or more like an orange colour? The manual does not mention the LED blinking *red*, but it is possible that a different LED was used, or that the green part of the LED is not working (red + green = amber-looking LED).

Comment: @AndrewMorton actually the battery is below 20 percent. The led is more orange then red

Comment: @Motte001 Then it appears that it is working correctly. You may want to take the time to read the manual and glance at the LED occasionally while you're doing that. It should turn to blinking green after some time, and you will (a) be relieved that all is well and (b) know more about your laptop :)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you so much. I would have read the manual or searched in the Internet, but I have not the manual here and very slow mobile Internet

Comment: @Motte001 You're welcome :) Please accept my answer as having solved the problem so that other people can see they don't need to add another answer. (It might be a few minutes before the system lets you tick it.)